# Error when running statement as whole but work when running one by one in top level

Tags: ocaml

So I was trying question 48 from [this link](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/99problems.html) in LearnOcamel, and I got a syntax error with "in" keyword in the second let statement in the editor if you look at my provided codes. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y52K9.png)

If I copy and past the codes in the first let statement the top level,  and then copy and past the code of the second let statement in the top level, It works fine. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpYyg.png)

This is really really strange. If I try to copy and past the entire codes in the top level then this won't work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qBUz.png)

```
let rec permuteBool n =
  match n with
  | 0 -> [[]]
  | k -> (List.map (fun x-> true::x) (permuteBool (n-1))) @ 
 (List.map (fun x -> false::x) (permuteBool (n-1)))


let table = [1;2;3] in (List.length table) |> permuteBool
```

Here is what I expect the code to output:

```
let table = [1;2;3] in (List.length table) |> permuteBool ;;

- : bool list list =
[[true; true; true]; [true; true; false]; [true; false; true];
 [true; false; false]; [false; true; true]; [false; true; false];
 [false; false; true]; [false; false; false]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This phrase

```
let table = [1;2;3] in (List.length table) |> permuteBool
```

is a toplevel (global) expression. Such expression need to be separated from toplevel definitions by a double semi-colon:

```
let rec permuteBool n =
  match n with
  | 0 -> [[]]
  | k -> (List.map (fun x-> true::x) (permuteBool (n-1))) @ 
 (List.map (fun x -> false::x) (permuteBool (n-1)))

;; let table = [1;2;3] in (List.length table) |> permuteBool
```

When you entered the two phrases separately, you ended up writing incidentally this required double semi-colon `;;`, thus the error disappeared.

A more idiomatic approach is to always bound such expression within a toplevel definition:

```
let rec permuteBool n =
  match n with
  | 0 -> [[]]
  | k -> (List.map (fun x-> true::x) (permuteBool (n-1))) @ 
 (List.map (fun x -> false::x) (permuteBool (n-1)))

let _ = (* here _ is used to discard the result *)
  let table = [1;2;3] in (List.length table) |> permuteBool
```

or if you don't want to discard the result:

```
let result = (* here _ is used to discard the result *)
  let table = [1;2;3] in (List.length table) |> permuteBool
```

Comment: Note: Without the `let result =` the code also fails to compile as toplevel (global) expressions are a quirk of the toplevel and not allowed in ocaml programs (neither is `;;`). So best get used to writing `let result =`.

Comment: No? Both `;;` and toplevel expressions are allowed in ocaml programs, even if there are not that idiomatic anymore.

Comment: I stand corrected. In this case it compiles with `;;`. But I've had cases where `;;` in compiled code would give errors while pasting it into the toplevel would work.